# window.open in phonegap

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova

I am new to phonegap. I am using phonegap with IOS. the problem i am facing is, JS function window.open('URL') is not working. it gives nothing. can anyone help me what is actually going on?

Thanks

Comment: What do you want to accomplish with that? What do you expect it to do? An iOS application doesn't have pop-ups or tabs for browsing, so that isn't going to work.

Comment: actually my current mobile web application contains popup for some kind of confirmations and after approving from popup it retrievs the data from server and proceed to next page. but window.open is not working in phonegap HTML page

Comment: You're just going to have to use a different approach. Look into lightboxes or something similar to create a div overlay on the page, and put your content in that. Or you could try adding a UIView in which you do the confirmation.

Comment: what about dialog of jquery mobile?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I used simple page with pop transition because jquery dialog is also works as a page but it effects your css, thats why i use a simple page with pop transition. and it appends in the current DOM due to which i have all of access to previous page form. just like openr in case of Window.open()
problem solved

Answer (score 0):

To show the confirmation box you need to do some thing like this

```
//process the confirmation dialog result
function onConfirm(button) {
alert('You selected button ' + button);
}

// Show a custom confirmation dialog
//
function showConfirm() {
navigator.notification.confirm(
    'You are the winner!',  // message
    onConfirm,              // callback to invoke with index of button pressed
    'Game Over',            // title
    'Restart,Exit'          // buttonLabels
);
}
```

Just invoke the showConfirm() on click of a button...

Comment: i am talking about popup confirmation not data retriving

Comment: Thanks... its 1 good solution, but i need the styled popup that's why i was opening popup but now what will be the good alternate for the window.open?

Comment: Check this out for some jquery mobile solutions http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2011/05/10-handy-jquery-mobile-tips-and-snippets-to-get-you-started/

Answer (score 0):

try this:`window.location ='http://www.google.com';`

```
window.location.href ='http://www.google.com';
```